# How to transform a (messy) list into multiple adjacency lists or an edge list in R?

Tags: r, matrix, data-structures, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I am trying to transform the Census’s FIPS codes, county-level unique identifiers, “adjacency list” into an actual adjacency lists or an edge list then eventually to an adjacency matrix. Here is the Census FIPS code data: http://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/reference/county_adjacency.txt.

## Problem: How to transform a difficult-to-wrangle list into several logical adjacency lists, then eventually a matrix?

The problem is that it is not an “adjacency list” in any conventional understanding of the phrase. I am very new to R so please excuse any errors or a lack of best practices…

My intuition tells me to do a loop through the list to subset the data into unique adjacency lists, convert each list to a matrix, then bind the matrix into one large binary matrix.  I searched online for how to do this but all examples contained very easy, clean data. :(

Census displays the FIPS codes like this:

```
"Bullock County, AL"    01011   "Barbour County, AL"    01005
        "Bullock County, AL"    01011
        "Macon County, AL"  01087
        "Montgomery County, AL" 01101
        "Pike County, AL"   01109
        "Russell County, AL"    01113
"Butler County, AL" 01013   "Butler County, AL" 01013
        "Conecuh County, AL"    01035
        "Covington County, AL"  01039
        "Crenshaw County, AL"   01041
        "Lowndes County, AL"    01085
        "Monroe County, AL" 01099
        "Wilcox County, AL" 01131
```

The textfile data is displayed like this when I read the url into R:

```
[1] "\"Autauga County, AL\"\t01001\t\"Autauga County, AL\"\t01001" "\t\t\"Chilton County, AL\"\t01021"                            "\t\t\"Dallas County, AL\"\t01047"                            
 [4] "\t\t\"Elmore County, AL\"\t01051"                             "\t\t\"Lowndes County, AL\"\t01085"                            "\t\t\"Montgomery County, AL\"\t01101"                        
 [7] "\"Baldwin County, AL\"\t01003\t\"Baldwin County, AL\"\t01003" "\t\t\"Clarke County, AL\"\t01025"                             "\t\t\"Escambia County, AL\"\t01053"                          
[10] "\t\t\"Mobile County, AL\"\t01097"
```

I used the stringr package’s regular expression to extract the actual codes. Now data looks like this:

```
> str(cleaner)
List of 100
 $ : chr [1:2] "01001" "01001"
 $ : chr "01021"
 $ : chr "01047"
 $ : chr "01051"
 $ : chr "01085"
 $ : chr "01101"
 $ : chr [1:2] "01003" "01003"
 $ : chr "01025"
 $ : chr "01053"
 $ : chr "01097"
 $ : chr "01099"
 $ : chr "01129"
 $ : chr "12033"
```

I can group the elements that follow the “first” item of the adjacency list, like so:

```
#function that groups FIPS codes, displays them by index value
reduce_fips <- function(locations, vect) {
  out <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(locations)) {
    if (i == length(locations)) {
      out[[i]] <- locations[i]:length(vect)
    } else {
      out[[i]] <- locations[i]:(locations[i + 1] - 1)
    }
  }
  out
}

out <- reduce_fips(adj_list_start, fips_codes)  #produces adj list values
#problem: some adj list start points contain 2 different values of fips codes 

fips_adj_df <- data.frame(cleaner = sapply(out, function(x) x[1]))
fips_adj_df
fips_adj_df$adjacent <- out  
#problem: how to transform this into a matrix or connected nodes
```

This produces output that looks like this. However, it is not logically correct and will be expensive to search through memory-wise.

```
cleaner                           adjacent
1        1                   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
2        7            7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
3       14 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22
4       23         23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
5       30         30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36
6       37             37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42
7       43         43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49
8       50             50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55
9       56             56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61
10      62     62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69
```

Ultimately, I want a binary matrix like this that displays whether or not the FIPS codes are geographically adjacent to each other. For example, assuming 100, 101, and 102 are adjacent to each other while 103 is only adjacent to 102, I would want the matrix to display the information like this.

```
             FIPS 
FIPS       100  101 102  103 
  102       1   1    1    1  
  101       1   1    1    0  
  100       1   1    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot going on in this question, so I will try to break it down.

First, you can get information from a text file using read.csv.

```
    df <- read.csv("county_adjacency.txt", sep="\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = FALSE)

    # Drop the names for the counties, you don't need them      
    df <- df[,c("V2","V4")]
```

Fill in the na values using na.locf from the zoo library.

```
    library(zoo)
    df$V2 <- na.locf(df$V2)
```

List your fips.  Use this to make your matrix.

```
    fips <-unique(df$V2)

    fips.matrix <- matrix(data=0, nrow = length(fips), ncol = length(fips), dimnames = list(fips,fips))
```

Fill the matrix with 1's based on the coordinates from from the txt file.

```
    df <- as.character(df)

    fips.matrix[as.matrix(df)] <-1
```